# Non Executing Loop and Sub Array

Tags: java, loops, sub-array

I am trying to find the most number of consonants in a row for a specific word in an array. I have a while loop in the middle that I have commented, but for some reason it does not execute. Does anyone know why? Also you might notice that I have an int spaces because I am trying to find a sub array of String[] words. How might I do that as well?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main
{
  public static void main (String[] args) 
  {
    System.out.print("Please enter a phrase to translate: ");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String str = scan.nextLine();  
    String[] words = str.split("\\s+");
    int spaces = (word.length - 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++)
    {
        String a = words[i].substring(0,1);
        int k = a.length();
        int n = words[i].length();
        if (!(a.contains("a") || a.contains("e") || a.contains("i") || a.contains("o") || a.contains("u")))
        {
            while (k < 5) // start while  
            {
                if (n > k)
                {
                    a = words[i].substring(0,k);
                    k = k + 1;
                    }
                }
            } // end while
        if (words[i].startsWith("a") || words[i].startsWith("e") || words[i].startsWith("i") || words[i].startsWith("o") || words[i].startsWith("u"))
        {
            System.out.print(words[i] + "way");
            }
        else if (!(a.contains("a") || a.contains("e") || a.contains("i") || a.contains("o") || a.contains("u")))
        {
            String answer = words[i].substring(k,n);
            System.out.print(answer + a + "ay");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: (Highlighting with `**` does not work in "code" sections.)

Comment: Is k ever less than 5?

Comment: k is the length of a substring (0,1), so yes, it ought to start out at length 1

Comment: It should always be less than five

Comment: Is it your intention to run that `while` loop only if your string `a` (which appears to be only a single character string) does not contain any vowels? `Cuz that's what you have there...

Comment: My intentions are to run the while loop if the string a has no vowels and if string a is more than one (anywhere up to four) consonant(s) long. A will then be assigned to the beginning consonants in a row.

Comment: For all words of length less than 4, does that go into infinite loop ?

Comment: Does it? What would you suggest I do?

Comment: @Gihadi But, since you do `String a = words[i].substring(0,1);`, I think the length of `a` is fairly limited (to 1)... At least on entering the loop...

Comment: yes, entering the loop a is limited to 1, but what i am trying to do is find if String a (being composed of only consonants) is larger than 1, up to 4. Why is the code not working? Sorry I'm fairly new to programming so I have no idea.

Comment: what exactly do you want a to be? That would help a lot

Comment: Ok, well String a is assigned to the beginning of any word in words[i]. The beginning is going to be all of the consonants that the word starts with in row. The reason I am doing this is because it is a Pig Latin translator. Tell me if this is confusing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your description of "trying to find the most number of consonants in a row for a specific word in an array", I would think something along these lines (not compiled or tested - just to show the approach) would be a lot simpler to follow/debug/test/maintain (also only looks at the current `word[i]` - an outer loop to iterate over your words is still needed:

```
String consgroups[] = word[i].split("[aeiou]"); // split on all vowels
int maxlen = consgroups[0].length, maxidx = 0;
for (int j = ; j < consgroups.length; ++j)    // iterate over groups and find max
  if (consgroups[j].length > maxlen)
  { maxidx = j;
    maxlen = consgroups[i].length;
  }
```

Given your comment about pig latin, I'm not sure why consonant groups other than at the beginning of the word are important, but perhaps I'm misunderstanding your description...

Edit: Now that I've looked a little harder, I think this approach might be more useful:

```
String vowels = "aeiou";
int i = 0;
while ((i < word.length) && (!vowels.contains(word.subSequence(i, i + 1))))
  ++i;
// now word[i] is the first non-vowel character in word
if (i == word.length) // word was all consonants
{ ...
}
else
  if (i) // word has a consonant prefix
  { ...
  }
  else // word starts with a vowel
  { ...
  }
```

Comment: I'll try this, and I am only looking for the consonant group at the beginning of the word

Comment: It cannot find words.subsequence and where you start the if statements, are they supposed to be the ones i already have or new ones inside of the while loop?

Comment: `String.subsequence()` has been in since JDK 1.4. I might have confused you by using `word` as a variable there - it would probably be `words[i]` in your case - the assumption was that `word` was a `String`, not your `words` which is a `String[]`...

Comment: It still cannot find the method. Also, do you know how to find a sub array or basically take an element away from an array in a similar fashion to string.substring(int,int)?

Comment: It's actually `String.subSequence()` - I missed the cAmELcAse bit. And `Arrays.copyOfRange()` might be what you want. For a full API reference, see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/).